# draw an arc of a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

how can I draw something like this?? thanks to everyone

[image]

I did this

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[black,thick,->] (0,0) -- (10,0) node[anchor=north west] {V};
    \draw[black,thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,10) node[anchor=north west] {E};
    \draw (5,5) circle (3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but I don't know how to move on.

Comment: I guess you use Geogebra to get your graph? Then you can File > Export > to PGF/TikZ.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Similar solution to the one provided by NBur but with another syntax:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[black,thick,->] (0,0) -- (10,0) node[anchor=north west] {V};
    \draw[black,thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,10) node[anchor=north west] {E};
    \draw (5,5) circle (3cm);
    \draw[red, line width=1mm, opacity=.5] (5,5)+(-10:3cm) arc[start angle=-10, end angle=-100, radius=3cm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for full MWE and the angular offset :)

Answer (score 8):

Just draw an arc over the circle.
I added a macro to store the radius.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex']
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Rayon}{3}
    \draw[black,thick,<->] (0,10) -- (0,0) node[pos=0, anchor=north west] {E} node[pos=1, anchor=south west] {O} -- (10,0) node[anchor=north west] {V};
    \coordinate (C) at (5,5);
    \draw (C) circle (\Rayon cm);
    \draw [very thick, red] ([xshift=\Rayon cm]C) arc (0:-90:\Rayon cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A detailed option; using nodes, node labels, arrows.meta, node names,font management,etc.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        font=\large\sffamily\bfseries,
        line width=1.5pt,
        >={Stealth[inset=0]},
        inner sep=2pt
    ]
    \fill
    (0,0)
        circle (4pt) node[label=45:O](O){}
    (10,0)
        circle (4pt) node[label=45:E](E){}
    (0,10)
        circle (4pt) node[label=45:V](V){};

    \draw
    (5,5)
        circle (3cm);
    \draw[red,line width=4pt,opacity=0.5]
    (5,5)++(0:3cm) arc (0:-85:3cm);
    \draw[->](O)--(E);
    \draw[->](O)--(V);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```